# TypeORM: Save entity with ManyToMany relation with custom field does not save properly

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have ManyToMany relationship of users and projects as follow:

```
// project.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => ProjectUser, projectUser => projectUser.project)
  projectUsers: ProjectUser[];

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', readonly: true })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  deletedAt: Date;

}
```

```
// user.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(type => ProjectUser, projectUser => projectUser.user)
  projectUsers: ProjectUser;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', readonly: true })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  deletedAt: Date;
}
```

```
// project_user.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class ProjectUser extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    projectId: number;

    @Column()
    userId: number;

    @Column()
    isUserCreator: boolean;

    @ManyToOne(type => Project, project => project.projectUsers)
    @JoinColumn()
    project: Project;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.projectUsers)
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User;
}
```

When I try to save a new project the new `ProjectUser` record does not save.

```
// project.service.ts


   async create(project: DeepPartial<Project>): Promise<Project> {
        ---> project  { name: 'project1', projectUsers: [{userId: 1, isUserCreator: true}]

        const projectToSave = Project.create(project)
        projectToSave.projectUsers = ProjectUser.create(project.projectUsers)
        return await projectToSave.save();
    }
```

Any ideas why cant I save the record in the related table?

Answer (score 3):

You only created `projectUsers` instances but not saving them.

Use below code for saving all of the `project` and `projectUsers`:

```js
const projectToSave = Project.create(project);
await projectToSave.save();

const projectUsers = ProjectUser.create(project.projectUsers);
projectUsers.forEach(p => p.project = projectToSave);
await projectUsers.save(projectUsers);
return projectToSave;
```

Or

```js
const projectUsers = await ProjectUser.save(ProjectUser.create(project.projectUsers));
const projectToSave = Project.create(project);
projectToSave.projectUsers = projectUsers;
return await projectToSave.save();
```

**Another solution**
You can just set `cascade` option in your entity to save automatically.

Comment: Execute save the way I did would work for one to many relation, we can call it - deep save. The power of it is that the orm will set the id created for the new project record to the projectUser new records as projectId. I know I can break it down to separate methods but I thought typeOrm have a solution for that. The second example you wrote will cause runtime error since you can't save projectUser array before the project creation.

Comment: to make it possible you have to set `cascade` property as true in your entity

Comment: I thought cascade is relevant only for mutations after creation, as update/delete... I'll try that.

Comment: cascade works on all operations: `cascade: ['insert', 'recover', 'remove', 'update', 'soft-remove']`